# removeItem(at: ) throw exception while successfully removed target file

Tags: swift

In my app, there is a function that removes the file at a given URL. When I run it on both iPad and iPad simulator, the removeItem(at: ) threw "file name" couldn’t be removed exception. However, the target file is actually deleted. Has anyone seen a similar issue? How can solve it? Thank you for your attention!

```
do {
    if FileManager().fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: URL)
    }
} catch {
    print("Error when delete file, \(error)")
    if !FileManager().fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
        print("File was deleted")
    }
}
```

The output is:

> Error when delete file, **Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "“A_wrinkle_in_time.epub” couldn’t be removed."** UserInfo={NSUserStringVariant=(
> Remove
> ), NSFilePath=/Users/frankw/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3175FB37-784E-4735-B3A9-40A9807DCA3F/data/Containers/Data/Application/97025FFC-C707-46E2-9E75-2CAF043022EB/Documents/A_wrinkle_in_time.epub, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000dc3780 {**Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"**}}
> File was deleted
> /Users/frankw/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3175FB37-784E-4735-B3A9-40A9807DCA3F/data/Containers/Data/Application/97025FFC-C707-46E2-9E75-2CAF043022EB/Documents

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be:

```
try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I tried removeItem(atPath: url.path). It produces the same error result.

Comment: maybe removeItem(at: url) not removeItem(atPath: url.path). Editing my answer.